# LINQ query to retrieve pivoted data taking too long

Tags: c#, sql, linq, pivot

I am working on a LINQ query which includes some pivot data as below

```
var q = data.GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.Med.Name,
                x.Med.GenericName,             
            }).ToList().Select(g =>
                new SummaryDto
                {
                    Name= g.Key.Name,
                    GenericName = g.Key.GenericName,                    
                    Data2012 = g.Where(z => z.ProcessDate.Year == 2012).Count(),
                    Data2013 = g.Where(z => z.ProcessDate.Year == 2013).Count(),
                    Data2014 = g.Where(z => z.ProcessDate.Year == 2014).Count(),
                    Data2015 = g.Where(z => z.ProcessDate.Year == 2015).Count(),
                    Data2016 = g.Where(z => z.ProcessDate.Year == 2016).Count(),
                    Data2017 = g.Where(z => z.ProcessDate.Year == 2017).Count(),
                    TotalCount = g.Count(),
                }).AsQueryable();

            return q;
```

The above LINQ takes too long as it queries `grp` `q.Count()*6 times`. If there are 10000  records, then it queries 60000 times
**Is there a better way to make this faster?**

Comment: Why not do the counts on the DB instead of loading all the data into memory via the `ToList`?

Comment: As far as I can remember .ToList() pulls the data from the DB and the rest of the calculation are done in the code - meaning it is just one query.  I would suggest to split the query into 2 sub queries and try to see which one takes longer to execute - pulling grouped data from DB or pivoting it.

Comment: @cycaHuH when I did that grouping the data is quick but pivoting took long

Comment: @juharr It didnt make any difference. In fact, I started off with doing counts on db and as it was too slow. I tried loading the data into memory

Comment: I have tried to run it locally on in memory on 60k records and it's pretty fast and I would try one more thing b/c it might be super slow due to a lazy-loading. If including process data won't help you might need to look at doing it in DB as @juharr suggested. Try: data.Include("ProcessDate").GroupBy or data.Include(d => d.ProcessDate).GroupBy.

Comment: Are you sure the `Count()` is the part of the query that is slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add year to the group key, then group again, and harvest per-group counts:

```
return data.GroupBy(x => new {
    x.Med.Name
,   x.Med.GenericName
,   x.ProcessDate.Year
}).Select(g => new {
    g.Key.Name
,   g.Key.GenericName
,   g.Key.Year
,   Count = g.Count()
}).GroupBy(g => new {
    g.Name
,   g.GenericName
}).Select(g => new SummaryDto {
    Name = g.Key.Name
,   GenericName = g.Key.GenericName
,   Data2012 = g.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Year == 2012)?.Count ?? 0
,   Data2013 = g.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Year == 2013)?.Count ?? 0
,   Data2014 = g.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Year == 2014)?.Count ?? 0
,   Data2015 = g.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Year == 2015)?.Count ?? 0
,   Data2016 = g.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Year == 2016)?.Count ?? 0
,   Data2017 = g.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Year == 2017)?.Count ?? 0
,   TotalCount = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
}).AsQueryable();
```

**Note:** This approach is problematic, because year is hard-coded in the `SummaryDto` class. You would be better off passing your DTO constructor an `IDictionary<int,int>` with counts for each year. If you make this change, the final `Select(...)` would look like this:

```
.Select(g => new SummaryDto {
    Name = g.Key.Name
,   GenericName = g.Key.GenericName
,   TotalCount = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
,   DataByYear = g.ToDictionary(i => i.Year, i => i.Count)
}).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: This line `g.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Year == 2012)?.Count ?? 0` is just one value. so, does count on it make any difference?

Comment: @DoIt `?.Count` is necessary because that's the field returned from the first-level `Select`. It is set to the count in the original group. Please give this query a try, and comment if you find an issue. `?.` operator is from C# 6, so it may not work for you. Then you'd need to bring the first group into memory, and use a helper function.

Comment: I did try and the query still times out for around 800k records

Comment: @DoIt This is almost certainly because of a full table scan required to compute `ProcessDate.Year`. Add a computed column to your table `alter mytable add ProcessYear as DATEPART(year, ProcessDate)`, map it as `ProcessYear`, and change your query to reference it. This should speed things up on the RDBMS side.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest grouping inside the group by year and then converting to a dictionary to access the counts. Whether it is faster to group with year first and then count in-memory depends on the distribution of the initial grouping, but with the database it may depend on how efficiently it can group by year, so I would test to determine which seems fastest.

In any case grouping by year after the initial grouping is about 33% faster than your query in-memory, but again it is vastly dependent on the distribution. As the number of initial groups increase, the grouping by Year queries slow down to match the original query. Note that the original query without any year counts is about 1/3 the time.

Here is grouping after the database grouping:

```
var q = data.GroupBy(x => new {
    x.Med.Name,
    x.Med.GenericName,
}).ToList().Select(g => {
    var gg = g.GroupBy(d => d.ProcessDate.Year).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Count());
    return new SummaryDto {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        GenericName = g.Key.GenericName,
        Data2012 = gg.GetValueOrDefault(2012),
        Data2013 = gg.GetValueOrDefault(2013),
        Data2014 = gg.GetValueOrDefault(2014),
        Data2015 = gg.GetValueOrDefault(2015),
        Data2016 = gg.GetValueOrDefault(2016),
        Data2017 = gg.GetValueOrDefault(2017),
        TotalCount = g.Count(),
    };
}).AsQueryable();
```